# API calls using salies between two PCF applications

Tags: api

```
I am trying to write a PCF application that makes and API calls running in
another PCF application. I am using Salis framework. Below is my code

   ConnectApp: function(req,res){
   var https = require('https');
   var options = {hostname: 'hhgconnectcentral1.cfapps.io',
   port: 443,
   path: '/connection_requests/addConnection',
   method: 'GET',
   headers: {'accept': 'application/json'}
    };
   console.info('Options prepared:');
   console.info(options);

   https.request(options, function(response) {
   var responseData = '';
   response.setEncoding('utf8');
   response.on('data', function(chunk){
    responseData += chunk;
    });

  console.info(JSON.parse(responseData));

  response.once('error', function(err){
 // Some error handling here, e.g.:
 res.serverError(err);
 });

response.on('end', function(){
 try {
 // response available as `responseData` in `yourview`
  res.locals.requestData = JSON.parse(responseData);
  } catch (e) {
  sails.log.info('Could not parse response from options.hostname: ' + e);
  }
    res.view('yourview');
      });
     }).end();
     }
```

When I run this code I get HTTP 502 error my app crashes and restarts. 
  I see  following in Logs.
  2017-06-29T13:54:42.99-0400 [RTR/5] OUT HHGPlayersCentral.cfapps.io - [2017-06-29T17:54:42.927+0000] "GET /player_requests/ConnectApp HTTP/1.1" 502 0 67 "-" "curl/7.43.0" "10.10.2.20:31899" "10.10.148.95:61129" x_forwarded_for:"45.27.236.192" x_forwarded_proto:"https" vcap_request_id:"2c302365-9e76-40ba-668a-8ea05f70fd1d" response_time:0.063139365 app_id:"247f9f87-9c61-44ee-a3d1-c06558ce9632" app_index:"0" x_b3_traceid:"26ded9881153c0ba" x_b3_spanid:"26ded9881153c0ba" x_b3_parentspanid:"-"
2017-06-29T13:54:42.99-0400 [RTR/5] OUT 
2017-06-29T13:54:42.99-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR undefined:1
2017-06-29T13:54:42.99-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
2017-06-29T13:54:42.99-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at Object.parse (native)
2017-06-29T13:54:42.99-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at ClientRequest. (/home/vcap/app/api/controllers/ConnectAppRequestController.js:65:23)
2017-06-29T13:54:42.99-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at ClientRequest.g (events.js:260:16)
2017-06-29T13:54:42.99-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
2017-06-29T13:54:42.99-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:169:7)
2017-06-29T13:54:42.99-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:433:21)
2017-06-29T13:54:42.99-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at   HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:97:23)

What wrong I am doing?